# EF Core error update-database when dependent entity has multiple reference to parent entity

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to EF Core. I have the two table which is almost similar to the following two tables as shown below:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }

    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public User Contributor { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Author")]
    public List<Post> AuthoredPosts { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Contributor")]
    public List<Post> ContributedToPosts { get; set; }
}
```

when i run update-database command, i am getting the following error

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Post_User_AuthorId' on table 'Post' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Can anyone please help what am i doing wrong and how to solve this in the best way?

Thanks

Comment: As you can see, the error is about `WorkflowRules` table, Post and User tables aren't involved.

Comment: i just gave these tables as an example. Anyway i have updated the error.

Answer (score -1):

Entity Framework is smart enough to figure it out the problems may occur when generating the tables and relationships between them accordingly to your models.

However this is not an error, this more like a warning in which you, as developer must make some additional configurations in order to generate the correct relationship. This is due to this part:

```
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public User Author { get; set; }

public int ContributorId { get; set; }
public User Contributor { get; set; }
```

Because you ware using the same type, `User` EF must be instructed how to act when one of those properties are changed (created, deleted, updated). This is also happening because you can have the same `Key` both for the Author and the Contributor and in this case EF must know how to handle it.

The solution is pretty simple, add some additional configs:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Relationships
    entity.HasOne(p => p.Author)
        .WithMany(p => p.AuthoredPosts)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.AuthorId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    entity.HasOne(p => p.Contributor)
        .WithMany(p => p.ContributedToPosts)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContributorId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

You can also specify what happens when the Update occurs.